# Problema para que cuando quito un producto del carrito, el valor total del mismo, se ajuste al nuevo valor del mismo

Tags: javascript

Me aparecio el siguiente error en mi proyecto, el cual consiste en que cuando elimino un elemento de mi carrito, este desaparece como es previsto, pero el valor del precio total del carrito no se ajusta (es decir que si tengo 4 productos que salen 1000$, y saco 1, deberia ser 3000, pero mi problema es que eso no esta sucediendo!)
Como deberia hacer para solucionar ese problema?

```
            const btnEliminarProducto = document.createElement('span');
            btnEliminarProducto.innerText = 'X';
            btnEliminarProducto.addEventListener("click", () => {
                eliminarProducto(product.id) 
                console.log(carrito)
                precioTotal.innerText = 
                console.log(precioTotal)
                carritoContent.style.display = 'none'
            });
            carritoContent.append(btnEliminarProducto)
            contenedorBtnEliminar.append(btnEliminarProducto)
        })
    
    
    
    
        headerModal.append(tituloModal,contenedorBtnCerrarModal)
    
    
    
        // Creando el footer que va a tener el total de los productos:
    
        const precioTotal = carrito.reduce((acc,el)=> acc + el.precio*el.cantidad,0)
        console.log(precioTotal)
    
        const contenedorPrecioCarrito = document.createElement('div');
        contenedorPrecioCarrito.className = 'contenedor-precio'
        contenedorPrecioCarrito.innerHTML = `Total a pagar: $${precioTotal}`
        contenedorModal.append(contenedorPrecioCarrito)


   
    }
   
}


carritoBtn.addEventListener('click',pintandoCarrito)

const eliminarProducto = (id) => {
    // Busca el producto en el carrito por su ID
    const foundProduct = carrito.find((product) => product.id === id);

    carrito = carrito.filter((carritoId)=>{
        return carritoId !== foundProduct
    })
    pintandoCarrito()

};
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y donde estas intentando hacer la resta?